# Calling document.body.innerHTML+= causes all other JS to stop working

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, workbench

I am attempting to make a very simple web part that allows me to add a `<script>` tag to the bottom of the `<body>` element. I am in the stage of using `gulp serve` to test my part in local workbench. I have created the web part  with the appropriate properties and as long as I keep one specific line commented, it works as a part, it just doesn't do the thing I need it to.

However as soon as I uncomment the key line: `document.body.innerHTML+=newHTML;` and load the part, all other JS on the page fails. I can no longer open properties or interact with the page sections. All the buttons stop working and I can't delete the part either.

When I inspect the body element, I can see that whatever I've set for `newHTML` is present just above the closing `</body>` tag, so I know that the `innerHTML` call was successful. I've tried using plain text here, too, and the same issue occurred so I know its an issue with the `innerHTML` call and not the script itself.

The most baffling thing about this is that my console doesn't have any errors. One would think that with a bunch of JS scripts and event listeners stopping working I'd see a bunch of errors in the console...nope. I'm usually pretty decent at working through errors, but this silent failure has me stumped.

Here is the relevant code from my primary `.ts` file:

```
export interface IAppendBodyPartWebPartProps {
  element: string;
}

export default class AppendBodyPartWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IAppendBodyPartWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    var newHTML = `${ this.properties.element }`;
    document.body.innerHTML+=newHTML;

  }
```

Please let me know if there are other pieces of the code that would be helpful to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your code using in below format:

```
private _JS: string = "https://*******.sharepoint.com/sites/CommunicationSiteTopic/Shared%20Documents/MyScript.js";

let articleRedirectScriptTag: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
articleRedirectScriptTag.src = this._JS;
articleRedirectScriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(articleRedirectScriptTag);
```

**Source**:

[Step By Step Procedure To Add A JS File To All Pages In A SPFx Modern Pages Using SharePoint Framework Extension](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/).

Comment: Wonderful thank you for the help. I had to remove the 'private' declaration as it was throwing errors, but making `_JS` into a string variable and removing the `this.` has gotten it working! In the persuit of learning, do you perhaps know why using `innterHTML` was causing the silent failure but `appendChild` isnt?